# Getting physical address from foursquare api at current venue geolocation

Tags: android, foursquare

Looking to geotag current location on android app and using foursquare api, get a physical address of the venue currently at.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know what venue you're at, you can just make a [venues detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) request, and the response will have the address of the venue if it's in our database.

If you're trying to straight-up reverse geocode (go from a ll -> address), Foursquare can't do that, but many other services can. [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) can get you from an ll to venues though.